# Cannot override prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden() method

Tags: swift, methods, overriding

I use this line of code in an app with XCode 10 in order to dim the home indicator on iPhone X and associated edgeless apple devices.

```html
    override func prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

Now the funny thing is, I have an **exact** copy of this app and on one copy the code works, whilst on the over the code does not compile:

> Method does not override any method from its superclass

Indeed when I start typing "prefers..." , prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden appears as a read-only property on the one hand, whilst it does appear as a method on the other hand, and gets the override prefix by default.

Thanks for taking the time,

Best

EDIT WITH SOLUTIONS thanks to **@inokey**

- Solution 1: check deployment (starting i0S 12, `prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden` cannot be overridden as a method)
- Solution 2 :

```html
override var prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden : Bool { return true }
```

Comment: Check the deploy target in the project settings. It may have something to do with iOS version set by default in Xcode 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that default deploy target in Xcode 10 is 12 and your previous project is 11 or 10, so it just reflects the changes in API.

[Changes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2887510-prefershomeindicatorautohidden?changes=latest_minor) in SDK indicate that this was changed

[image]

Comment: Thanks! And indeed the deploy target is different. However when I change the deploy target to 11 the error persists.
In addition, how do I deal with the change now? any idea?

Comment: Try building the app again after changing deployment target sometimes it doesn't reflect the change right away in the editor.

Comment: I did and I get a "build failed"

Comment: Where exactly do you override this variable? Do you have any other external dependencies that may rely on previous implementation of this property?

Comment: I put it in the end, just before the ending brace of the UIViewClass. Same place for both version (the one that works and the one that does not)

Comment: Did you mean UIViewController class? Are you using some custom view controller that may depend on external libraries?

Comment: I put it in here : class ViewController: UITableViewController { }. No external librairies involved. I have also double checked project editor to see whether I could spot a difference (in deployment associated parameters) but no.

Comment: Okay, Im a little confused now but can you repeat the setup that doesn't work. I mean iOS version and where exactly error appears.

Comment: I have edited the original message. I hope it helps. Thanks again for taking the time!!!

Comment: I might sound noob, but it does not work with var either. :(

Comment: `override var prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden { return true }` doesn't work?

Comment: @Chris It still shows an error that it doesn't override any properties of a super class?

Comment: It did throw the same error but in fact you were very close!!! Correct syntax is: `override var prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden : Bool { return true }` I needed to declare the type and then write the closure {} Thanks a lot for having taken the time!!!

Comment: @Chris well that was stated in the original answer on a screenshot there's obvious type annotation for a stored property. Anyway, if the problem is solved please accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

in Xcode 10 = Swift 4.2 (Sep 2018)

Just use the code below:

```
override var prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden: Bool { return true }
```

Comment: Took me hours to realize that I needed to override var and not func. Thank you, sir!

Comment: @Repose, this shows how crappy Apple documentation is. The single disdain attitude from them, not to include a F***ing example, makes us all suffer and waste time.