# How to override method not available in target platform, but available in Base SDK

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to add support for newer iOS devices while maintaining compatibility with older ones. Using Xcode 11.1,  I've set the target iOS platform to 9.3, in General -> Deployment Info -> Target.

In Build Settings, the Base SDK just says iOS, so I'm assuming it's always the latest that Xcode supports.

I'm trying to make the Home Indicator disappear in iPhoneX and 11, but for that you have to override this method,

```
override func prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden() -> Bool
{
    return true
}
```

However, I get this build error:

```
Method does not override any method from its superclass
```

I tried using the `@available` syntax like this,

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
override func prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden() -> Bool
{
    return true
}
```

But I get the same build error. If I check the Quick Help on that method, it doesn't point to Apple's documentation, whereas on another game where the target is set to iOS 11, the Quick Help does point to the right place.

I don't want to change the target to a newer one because that would break compatibility with older phones. Is this a matter of hard-coding the Base SDK or something?

Edit:

I accepted the first answer as valid, but I thought I would write down some clarifications, just in case someone else gets stuck in something similar:

- If you have updated your project to the latest Swift, the Base SDK should be the latest by default.
- If you haven't, your old code will still compile. That's why `func prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden()` still works in my other project, since it used to be a function (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52387441/1765629) and I haven't updated that project to Swift 5.
- The above is independent of the deployment target, so it seems I don't even need the `@available` in this case. I assume the value will be ignored in older iOS targets.

Comment: It is not a func, but a variable: `var prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden: Bool { get }`. Check here: [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2887510-prefershomeindicatorautohidden)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Starsky points out,

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
override var prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden: Bool {
        return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I seen now that it used to be a function but it's changed now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52387441/1765629